# Designing a news display

Tags: html, html-table

Right now, I am posting news and updates to my website like this:

```
<table class = "myclass">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <i>9/23/11</i><br>
      Update goes here.
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <i>9/17/11</i><br>
      Another update here
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

It seems like there must be a better way to do this. I'm not a professional and am looking for something basic and simple to do this job. Is there a better way?

Comment: What do you not like about this current way? We offer a lot of suggestions, but each has a cost associated with it. You could start using a CMS, where you've got a WYSIWYG editor to update the pages - but that requires installing, configuring and understanding the CMS.

Comment: Just based on looks, the only real problem is the vertical spacing between the cells. With this solution, I guess I would have to add another <br> after the update unless there is an option for vertical cell spacing. Other than that, it just seemed like a very manual way to do a very common task. I'd rather not install anything on my end, and only if it is a simple process on the webserver end.

Comment: If you want more vertical spacing, apply a margin or a padding, don't go adding meaningless `<br />`'s ...

Answer (score 0):

Use `Div`s. 
So your HTML would look like this

```
  <table class = "myclass">
<tr>
<td>
      <div class='date'>9/23/11</div>
     <div id='update1' >Update Goes Here</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
    <div class='date'>9/23/11</div>
    <div id='update2' >Another update here</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and your css

```
.date{
    font-style : italic;
}
```

Check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/45AE9/10/

I have used ids for the update related elements in case u want to update the data at a later stage u can access these div elements by their ids

Answer (score 0):

I would use divs...

css:

```
.update div:first-child{font-style: italic;}
```

html:

```
<div class="myclass">
    <div class="update">
        <div>9/23/11</div>
        <div>Update goes here.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="update">
        <div>9/17/11</div>
         <div>Another update here</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/P35NT/